# Duda con if y elif

Tags: python, funciones, condiciones, algoritmos, spyder

Estoy realizando una actividad en donde debo aplicar un descuento si hay una compra por igual o más a 5 prendas del 20 por ciento, y si la compra es de igual o más de 10 prendas entonces aplicar un descuento del 25 por ciento (el valor de cada prenda es de 60000).

El código lo realicé así:

```py
prendas = print("introduzca el numero de prendas: ")

numero_prendas = int(input(" "))

if (numero_prendas >= 5):
    print("aplica al descuento del 20 por ciento")
    print((60000*numero_prendas)*0.20)
elif (numero_prendas >=10):
    print("aplica al descuento del 25 por ciento")
    print("aplica al descuento del 25 por ciento")
else:
    print(total)
```

El problema / duda es qué solamente se ejecuta el *if* y el *else* , pero no el *elif* (osea solamente se ejecuta y se muestra el descuento del 20 por ciento, sin importar si el número de prendas es igual o mayor de 10).

Sin embargo , si en vez de escribir el elif, escribo dos if, si se ejecuta normalmente cada descuento respectivo, pero el código muestra tanto el descuento de si son más o igual  de 5 prendas como si es de más o igual de 10 prendas, y la idea es qué se lea cada uno.

¿Alguna ayuda? Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema está con que para que entre al `elif`, TIENE QUE DAR FALSO a la condición del `if`.

Entonces, si `numero_prendas` es mayor que 10 (condición del `elif`), por lo tanto también es mayor que 5 (condición del `if`, osea que entrará primero a esta y no entrará al `elif`).

Entonces, si el número que elijas es, digamos, 15; tu querrás que entre al `elif`, pero resulta que 15 tambien es mayor que 5, así que sólo va a entrar al `if` de mayor a 5 y ya va a ejecutar el `elif`.

Intenta cambiando el orden de tus condiciones para que primero se evalue del mayor al menor, es decir, primero el mayor de 10 prendas y luego el de mayor a 5:

```py
prendas = print("introduzca el numero de prendas: ")

numero_prendas = int(input(" "))

if numero_prendas >= 10:
    print("aplica al descuento del 25 por ciento")
    print("aplica al descuento del 25 por ciento")
elif numero_prendas >= 5:
    print("aplica al descuento del 20 por ciento")
    print((60000*numero_prendas)*0.20)
else:
    print(total)
```

Tu código final te debería de quedar algo así:

```py
prendas = print("introduzca el numero de prendas: ")

numero_prendas = int(input(" "))

COSTO_PRENDA = 60000
descuento = 1
costo_final = numero_prendas * COSTO_PRENDA

if numero_prendas >= 10:
    print("aplica al descuento del 25 por ciento")
    descuento = 0.25
elif numero_prendas >= 5:
    print("aplica al descuento del 20 por ciento")
    descuento = 0.20

costo_final = numero_prendas * COSTO_PRENDA * descuento

print(f"El costo final es de: {costo_final}")
```

Que ejecutado daría:

```bash
$ python desc.py
introduzca el numero de prendas:
 2
El costo final es de: 120000
$ python desc.py
introduzca el numero de prendas:
 6
aplica al descuento del 20 por ciento
El costo final es de: 72000.0
$ python desc.py
introduzca el numero de prendas:
 11
aplica al descuento del 25 por ciento
El costo final es de: 165000.0
```

Comment: Lol, más puntos negativos sin explicación?

Comment: Igual mi respuesta es la aceptada :D Ah! La justicia de hacer bien tu trabajo y con gusto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, ten una excelente noche. Gran aporte.

Answer (score 1):

Es por el orden de las condiciones, si `numero_prendas` es 15, primero se evalúa la condición `numero_prendas >= 5` y eso es verdadero así que se queda en esa condición.

Una solución es colocar las condiciones en orden inverso:

```
if numero_prendas >= 10:
        print("aplica al descuento del 25 por ciento")
        print("aplica al descuento del 25 por ciento")
 elif numero_prendas >= 5:
        print("aplica al descuento del 20 por ciento")
        print((60000*numero_prendas)*0.20) 
 else:
        print(total)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, aprecio tu ayuda.